Kernel module to copy usb content
For a school project, I need to code a kernel module to copy files from a USB flash drive automatically when it's plugged in. I know it is not appropriate for kernel side but it is what it is.
I have a code that uses a notifier to know when a usb stick is plugged in and launches the function that copies the data from the stick using a URB. I've gone through the documentation several times and I think I've got the right implementation, but when I insert the mod and plug in the usb stick, I only get the first 36 bytes of the stick (the name of the stick). I have no idea how to read the data instead.
I am using Ubuntu 23.10
Here is the code:
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 1028 

static unsigned int get_pipe(struct usb_device *dev)
{
    struct usb_host_interface *iface_desc;
    struct usb_endpoint_descriptor *endpoint;
    unsigned int i, j, pipe = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "nb inter : %d\n", dev->actconfig->desc.bNumInterfaces);
    for (i = 0; i < dev->actconfig->desc.bNumInterfaces; i++) {
        iface_desc = dev->actconfig->interface[i]->cur_altsetting;
        printk(KERN_INFO "nb endp : %d", iface_desc->desc.bNumEndpoints);

        for (j = 0; j < iface_desc->desc.bNumEndpoints; j++) {
            endpoint = &iface_desc->endpoint[j].desc;

            if ((endpoint->bmAttributes & USB_ENDPOINT_XFERTYPE_MASK) == USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK && (endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_DIR_IN))
            {
                pipe = usb_rcvbulkpipe(dev, endpoint->bEndpointAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_NUMBER_MASK);
                return pipe;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void urb_complete_handler(struct urb *urb)
{
    if (urb->status == 0 && urb->actual_length > 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Received Data Length: %d\n", urb->actual_length);
        print_hex_dump(KERN_DEBUG, "Received USB Data: ", DUMP_PREFIX_NONE, 16, 1, urb->transfer_buffer, urb->actual_length, true);
    }
    else if (urb->status == 0 && urb->actual_length == 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "No more data to read.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "URB failed with status: %d\n", urb->status);
    }

    kfree(urb->context);
    usb_free_urb(urb);
}

static int fetch_datas(struct usb_device* dev)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned char *buf;
    struct urb *urb;
    unsigned int pipe;

    buf = kmalloc(BUFFER_LENGTH, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buf)
        return -1;

    urb = usb_alloc_urb(0, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!urb)
    {
        kfree(buf);
        return -1;
    }

    pipe = get_pipe(dev);
    if (pipe == 0)
    {
        usb_free_urb(urb);
        kfree(buf);
        return -1;
    }

    usb_fill_bulk_urb(urb, dev, pipe, buf, BUFFER_LENGTH, urb_complete_handler, buf);

    ret = usb_submit_urb(urb, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (ret)
    {
        usb_free_urb(urb);
        kfree(buf);
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int usb_notifier_fn(struct notifier_block *nb, unsigned long action, void *data)
{
    struct usb_device *dev = data;

    switch (action) {
        case USB_DEVICE_ADD:
            printk(KERN_INFO "USB device added: INFO=%s\n", dev->serial);
            printk(KERN_INFO "USB NAME : %s\n", dev->product);
            fetch_datas(dev);
            break;
        case USB_DEVICE_REMOVE:
            printk(KERN_INFO "USB device removed\n");
            break;
    }

    return NOTIFY_OK;
}

static struct notifier_block usb_nb = {
    .notifier_call = usb_notifier_fn,
};

static int __init usb_notifier_init(void)
{
    usb_register_notify(&usb_nb);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit usb_notifier_exit(void)
{
    usb_unregister_notify(&usb_nb);
    printk(KERN_INFO "USB notifier unregistered\n");
}

module_init(usb_notifier_init);
module_exit(usb_notifier_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Willi");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("USB copy mod");


I've tried several methods to copy the contents of the usb but usb_bulk_urb seems to be the best for this project.
I've tried calling the city again and again to try and read more data but I only get these 36 bytes.
I've tried changing USB but I still get 36 bytes with the name of the USB.

I suspect you can't just start reading data from an endpoint, you might have to tell the USB drive what block you want to read data from and stuff like that.  You will need to read the relevant parts of the Mass Storage Device Class specification published by the USB Implementer's Forum so you know what kind of USB messages the drive expects.  You might also want to get a USB protocol analyzer and see what USB messages get sent when you read using the standard USB stack (e.g. cat /dev/sdc > file).
